# What is wrong with this macro in Clojure?

Tags: functional-programming, macros, clojure

```
(defmacro nif [expr pos zer neg]
  '(condp = (Integer/signum ~expr) 
     -1 ~neg
     0 ~zer
     1 ~pos))
```

I get this error.

```
1:1 user=> #<Namespace Chapter7Macros>
1:2 Chapter7Macros=> (nif 1 (+ 2 2) (- 2 2) (- 3 2))
1:3 Chapter7Macros=> java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: expr in this context (repl-1:57)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the quote (*'*) by a backtick (*`*) to enable syntax-quoting.

Comment: The font for On Lisp makes it hard (for me, and apparently for OP as well) to tell ' from \`. In general, when you're working with macros you want \`. (backtick, in case anyone is having trouble with my font!)

Answer (score 3):

In general using (macroexpand-1 '(nif 1 ... )) will help a lot by showing you the code your macro is actually translating into.